# Ext.tabPanel maximize vertical height

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs3

I'm new to Ext JS. I have a problem with height of Ext.tabPanel.
My Ext JS code:
HTML Code:

```
<div id="TabPanel"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
Ext.onReady(function () {
var ex2 = new Ext.TabPanel({plain: true,renderTo: TabPanel,
items: [{title: 'Tab 1',
 html: '<div>Hello</div>'}
{title: 'Tab 2',html:'<div">Hello</div>'}]});})
</script>
```

How can I extend my tab panel on maximum height?

Comment: You've tagged it as Ext4, Ext 4.1 and Ext3. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    width: 500,
    height: 700,
    activeTab: 0,
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Tab 1',
            bodyPadding: 10,
            html : '<div>Hello from tab1</div>'
        },
        {
            title: 'Tab 2',
            html : '<div>Hello from tab2</div>'
        }
    ],
    renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering your tab into `div`, so add `height=100%` to the div attributes:

`<div id="TabPanel" height="100%"></div>`